# Copy a Python module/package, change its behavior & then compare its behavior with the original?

Tags: python, class, simulator

I'm trying to write a program that can simulate different scenarios.

The model of the world is represented by various python objects, typically functions and classes. I want to retain both the original and new versions of the world.

Conceptually, I think I would like to define the world as it currently stands, then change bits about it, and simulate both.

For example, I'm expecting something like this:

```
import world
from simulator import simulate
from world_changer import change, copy_world

world0 = world
world1 = change(copy_world(world))

results0 = simulate(world0)
results1 = simulate(world1)

print results0, results1
```

The world typically will be a package as there's a lot going on in it, and classes within modules seems a natural way to represent a stateful process.

I really don't know if this is possible, or if I'm thinking about this in the right way.

Comment: I always had the "problem" when I worked in the python shell that when I changed the module I had to import it again. Maybe this can be useful for you.
import world as world1

Comment: and import world as world2

Comment: this will just provide two references to the same object, afaik

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very abstract, but dependency injection seems like a plausible alternative:

```
import world
from simulator import simulate
from sub_worlds import sub_world_0, sub_world_1

world0 = world.World(sub_world_0)
world1 = world.World(sub_world_1)
...
```